# npm install fails with bcrypt@3.0.7 install

Tags: npm

I am trying to install [verdaccio-bitbucket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verdaccio-bitbucket) npm package.

```
$ npm install -g verdaccio-bitbucket
```

when I install is locally on my mac, it works fine with no errors.

When I run this on AWS Linux 2 AMI, I get the following:

```
[ec2-user@ip-9-9-0-76 verdaccio]$ npm install -g verdaccio-bitbucket                                                                                                                                                           

> bcrypt@3.0.7 install /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v79-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.7 and node@13.6.0 (node-v79 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
make: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.154-128.181.amzn2.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin/node" "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ec2-u
ser/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdac
cio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v79"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v13.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin/node /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-bu
ild --module=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib
/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.154-128.181.amzn2.x86_64
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin/node" "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v13.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin/node /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ec2-user/.nv
m/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbuck
et/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                                                                                                       
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/.npm/_logs/2020-01-12T09_28_32_248Z-debug.log
[ec2-user@ip-9-9-0-76 verdaccio]$
```

**UPDATE**

Following @wobr answer, I did the following from [AWS User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html)

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Now I get the following:

```
[ec2-user@ip-9-9-0-76 verdaccio]$ npm install -g verdaccio-aws-s3-storage                                                                                                                                                       
+ verdaccio-aws-s3-storage@9.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                
updated 1 package in 1.049s
[ec2-user@ip-9-9-0-76 verdaccio]$ npm install -g verdaccio-bitbucket                                                                                                                                                            

> bcrypt@3.0.7 install /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v79-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.7 and node@13.6.0 (node-v79 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
make: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
make: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/verdaccio-bitbucket/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
+ verdaccio-bitbucket@2.0.0
added 81 packages from 83 contributors in 5.459s
[ec2-user@ip-9-9-0-76 verdaccio]$
```

Comment: You need a c++ compiler present. Try something like `apt install g++ make`

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-9-9-0-76 verdaccio]$ cat /proc/version                                                                                                                                                                             
Linux version 4.14.154-128.181.amzn2.x86_64 (mockbuild@ip-10-0-1-129) (gcc version 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6) (GCC)) #1 SMP Sat Nov 16 21:49:00 UTC 2019

Comment: That doesn't mean g++ is available on the command line.

Comment: Looks good to me. Is anything remaining?

Comment: @wobr, when I run the same command on my Mac, I don't get any warnings, how can I solve this?

Comment: The available prebuilt releases can be seen here, various bcrypt, node, is versions: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases. I guess you can pick one of those, or add to the list, or compile from source (which is where you are currently at)

Answer (score 1):

step 1 : https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions

step 2 : npm i bcrypt@3.0.6

**Version Compatibility** (18/01/2019)

nodejs 12 >= bcrypt@3.0.6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIQIt.png)